# Can I scroll on a side panel using Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, google-maps

Essentially title - I've seen plenty of methods here for scrolling on webpages but not on the side panel of a webpage. Here's the code - the scrolling part seems to have no effect:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)  # chromedriver path
driver.get('https://www.google.com/maps/search/gas/@40,-75.2,12z/data=!4m2!2m1!6e2')
time.sleep(3)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 100)")
time.sleep(3)
```

[Here's the page](https://www.google.com/maps/search/gas/@40,-75.2,12z/data=!4m2!2m1!6e2)  I'm trying to access. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scroll to a specific element using

```
els = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.TFQHme')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", els[-1])
```

In this example the last one loaded.
The list will grow as you scroll down, to keep scrolling, just retrieve the list again.

You can implement an infinite scroll using the following:

```
def infinite_scroll(driver):
    number_of_elements_found = 0
    while True:
        els = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.TFQHme')
        if number_of_elements_found == len(els):
            # Reached the end of loadable elements
            break

        try:
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", els[-1])
            number_of_elements_found = len(els)

        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            # Possible to get a StaleElementReferenceException. Ignore it and retry.
            pass
```

Comment: Finally got around to this project again and this worked like a dream. Thanks so much.